# Load Contacts list in alphabetic order using CNContact in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cncontact

i have an Array contain list Contacts has been fetch.
Here is my sample code

```
func getData() -> [CNContact]  {
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    let keysToFetch = [
        CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
        CNContactEmailAddressesKey,
        CNContactDatesKey
        ] as [Any]
    var allContainers: [CNContainer] = []
    do {
        allContainers = try contactStore.containers(matching: nil)
    } catch {
        print("err")
    }

    var listContacts: [CNContact] = []
    for container in allContainers {
        let fetchPredecate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainer(withIdentifier: container.identifier)
        do {
            let containerResult = try contactStore.unifiedContacts(matching: fetchPredecate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch as! [CNKeyDescriptor] )
            listContacts.append(contentsOf: containerResult)
        } catch {

        }
    }

    // sort by name given
    let result = listContacts.sorted(by: {
        (firt: CNContact, second: CNContact) -> Bool in firt.givenName < second.givenName
    })

    return result
}
```

And i need to load to UITableView look like this
[image]

so, how can i do that ? Thanks you ! 
p/s: sorry my bad english

Comment: I think this library is appreciate with your purpose:
https://cocoapods.org/pods/BLContactsViewController

Comment: Did you finally figure it out?